# Lightning Web Components focus not working

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I am working on a requirement wherein I display a list of error messages on the parent component and there are certain lightning input fields in the child component.

On click of the error message, I need to highlight the corresponding field in child component in red, showing error is related to that field.

SO, for example. I have an error message that says Name should not be empty, in that case, I need to highlight the input field for Name in the child component.

To achieve this, I'm passing the id value to a method in the child component, which relates to both the **id** and **data-id** attributes of the input field to be highlighted/focused on.

I used a console message in child component method to verify if I'm getting the correct data-id, and it sends the correct data-id but the focus doesn't seem to be working .

Below is the code snippet of how I'm trying to focus.

```
@api
    focusOnError(sfieldId){
        /* eslint-disable no-console */
        console.log('Id Recieved in child component : ',sfieldId);
        this.template.querySelector(`[data-id="${this.sfieldId}"]`).focus();
    }
```

And this is the css that I used :

```
lightning-input:focus { 
    outline: none !important;
    border-color: #719ECE;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #719ECE;
}
```

Can someone please tell the right way to use focus to take to the specific field and highlight.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to modify a namespaced lwc component styling,  you wont be able too. I suggest you take a read at the lwc doc on css and lightning web components, more precisely, shadow dom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with Eric as its difficult to say without looking at the rest of the markup.

But, what I can still notice from the markup given above is that you're trying to refer the global property sfieldId by using **this.sfieldId** in the querySelector, while you might have to use the argument value passed to the method, which is the local method property.

So try changing it to :

```
this.template.querySelector(`[data-id="${sfieldId}"]`).focus();
```

Comment: Thanks Ashutosh. worked perfectly for me.